# Docker/Boot2Docker/Fig + RabbitMQ host issue; pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, boot2docker, fig

I have just started learning RabbitMQ and Docker/Fig. I have a very simple example with 3 fig containers, one each for the Rabbit Server, Producer, and Consumer.  In `/etc/hosts` I have set my `boot2docker ip` to an alias of `dockerhost`:

```
/etc/hosts
192.168.59.103    dockerhost
```

When I `fig up -d` the RabbitMQ server, everything works as it should; I can open a browser and go to `dockerhost:PORTNUM` and access the RabbitMQ control panel.

In my RabbitMQ producer I have set the connection host to `dockerhost`:

```
/producer.py
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
    host=config['RabbitMQ']['hostname'],
    ...
    ))
```

where my config file looks like this:

```
/config.ini
[RabbitMQ]
hostname    = dockerhost
```

However when I run `fig up -d` on the RabbitMQ producer I receive a connection error:

```
rabbitworker_1 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 301, in _adapter_connect
rabbitworker_1 |     raise exceptions.AMQPConnectionError(error)
rabbitworker_1 | pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`
```

I can get the RabbitMQ producer to work properly by entering the `boot2docker ip` directly into the RabbitMQ hostname instead of the `dockerhost` alias:

```
/config.ini
[RabbitMQ]
hostname    = 192.168.59.103
```

The above change gets everything working properly.

My question is how can I get the RabbitMQ producer to work by using `hostname = dockerhost` instead of entering the actual IP address?

## Update

Here is my RabbitMQ server `fig.yml` which works with `dockerhost`:

```
rabbit:
    image: mikaelhg/docker-rabbitmq
    ports:
     - "5672:5672"
     - "15672:15672"
```

And here is my RabbitMQ producer `fig.yml` and `Dockerfile` which does NOT work with `dockerhost`:

```
/fig.yml
rabbitworker:
    build: .
    volumes:
     - .:/opt/worker
     - ./log:/var/log
    command: supervisord -n

/Dockerfile
FROM python3-rabbit-producer

COPY . /opt/worker
WORKDIR /opt/worker

RUN pip3.4 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

Comment: It's normal it doesn't work with `dockerhost` as your container doesn't have access to your hosts file. Could you provide your `fig.yml` file please?

Comment: @CélineAussourd I have updated my question with the `fig.yml` of the RabbitMQ server which works with `dockerhost` and the `fig.yml` and `Dockerhost` of the RabbitMQ producer which does NOT work with `dockerhost`.  If it's normal that it doesn't work with `dockerhost`, why does the RabbitMQ server container work with `dockerhost`?

Comment: It's working from your browser, right? If you enter your container and try to access dockerhost:PORTNUM I expect it won't work as the container can't resolve `dockerhost`

Comment: by the way, if you are using volumes for `/opt/worker`, then you don't need to COPY `/opt/worker` in your Dockerfile (unless I missed something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using fig, I suggest you use the real power of fig by creating 1 unique `fig.yml` file and link the containers for them to communicate. So you would edit your current RabbitMQ producer `fig.yml` so you get:

```
rabbit:
    image: mikaelhg/docker-rabbitmq
    ports:
     - "5672:5672"
     - "15672:15672”

rabbitworker:
    build: .
    volumes:
     - .:/opt/worker
     - ./log:/var/log
    links: 
       - rabbit
    command: supervisord -n
```

and then edit your config file to get:

```
/config.ini
[RabbitMQ]
hostname    = rabbit
```

If you really want to keep your config file as it is and use `dockerhost`, then you can edit the rabbitworker links in `fig.yml` this way:

```
    links: 
       - rabbit:dockerhost
```

but you have to be aware that `dockerhost` will resolve to your RabbitMQ server container IP (and not your host IP).

Comment: Thank you Celine.  Your answer provided some clarity.  Quick side question: Is there a way to set the container's hosts file?  For example, I can enter the boot2docker shell by `boot2docker ssh`.  I can then `sudo vi /etc/hosts` to open the container's host file.  I would think I could add: `192.168.59.103   dockerhost` and that would also solve my problems but that does not work, do you know why this method does not work?

Comment: if you add the line in the `/etc/hosts` file and don't exit the container, I don't know why this does not work. Apparently you can add a line to `/etc/hosts` using the option `--add-host` when you run a container: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#network-settings